# How to set k8s not to check metric server?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When running "helm install" command, the following error is thrown.

*Error: could not get apiVersions from Kubernetes: unable to retrieve the complete list of server APIs: metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request*****

`kubectl get APIService` has the following line in its outut
*v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io                 kube-system/metrics-server   False (MissingEndpoints)   146d*

How to resolve it?
Why is metric server error coming when there is no metric server POD in my system ?

Comment: what are you trying to install using helm?

Comment: I am trying to install my deployment.

Comment: not a software from helm chart repo? And do you have metrics server installed? Can you share output of `kubectl get pods -A`